# How can I generate bar code for a product with information in android?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I used ZXing library for generating the bar code.

Currently I can pass String value for converting string content to bar code image.
But I need to generate bar code with product information. 
Like Product name, description, manufactured date and so on..
How can I do that in android?

Please help!

Comment: Put your product information in a String, possible in a JSON format and then after scan retrieve the json format and parse it to get all details.

Comment: This is a lot of information, too much to hold in a bar code. Usually,the bar code would just contain a key that allows to fetch more information about the product from a database.

Comment: Then, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Here is some widely used bar code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number, Designing a product database is far too broad for a question on SO.

Comment: I didn't get any best answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to go with a 2D barcode if you want to go any longer than 60 or so characters, especially on a device like a smartphone.

You can pack a maximum of around 4k of alphanumeric data in the largest QR Code and about 1.5K in a single PDF417, but unless your screen surface area is large and fixed in space, you are going to have trouble scanning a symbol that dense.

2D barcodes are a pain to work with on the generation and scanning side. Not to mention the code you would have to write to validate and parse. Scanning and printing one small barcode lets you focus on application logic.

I recommend what the others are telling you to do. Put the product information in a persistent key-value store and put the key in a 1D barcode. The key, when scanned, can retrieve a JSON or CSV string telling you all you want to know about the product. That's how EAN/UPC encodings work, and they have a pretty good track record.